# Prove a inequality property of convex function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, convex-analysis

> **Problem:** Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be the convex function. Let $x_1,x_3
> \in E$ (Euclidean space in $\mathbb{R}^n$) and $x_2 \in (x_1,x_3)$.
> Prove that $$\dfrac{f(x_3) -f(x_2)}{\Vert x_3-x_2 \Vert} \ge\dfrac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{\Vert x_2-x_1\Vert}.$$

**My attempt:** Since $x_2 \in (x_1,x_3)$ then there exists $t \in (0,1)$ such that $x_2 = tx_1 + (1-t)x_3$. Thus we have
$$f(x_3) - f(x_2)  \ge f(x_3)-tf(x_1)-(1-t)f(x_3) = tf(x_3)-tf(x_1).$$
Therefore
$$\dfrac{f(x_3)-f(x_2)}{\Vert x_3-x_2\Vert} \ge \dfrac{t}{\vert t \vert}\dfrac{f(x_3)-f(x_1)}{\Vert x_3-x_1\Vert} \ge -\dfrac{f(x_3)-f(x_1)}{\Vert x_3-x_1\Vert} = \dfrac{f(x_1)-f(x_3)}{\Vert x_1-x_3\Vert}.$$

I have tried many different ways to have a result like the solution above but I failed. I wonder that the problem is right or not?

Comment: "*such that $x_2 = tx_1 + (1-t)f(x_3)$*" $\;-\;$ You must have meant $\,x_2=tx_1+(1-t)x_3\,$ there. Note that $t = \frac{\|x_2-x_3\|}{\|x_1-x_3\|}$ and use that $f\left(tx_1+(1-t)x_3\right) \le t f(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_3)\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I have tried this way but I can't make $f(x_2) appear in both side of inequality. Can you tell me more details?

Comment: $\|x_3-x_1\| = \|x_3-x_2\|+\|x_2-x_1\|\,$ since $\,x_2 \in (x_1,x_3)\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since $x_2 \in (x_1,x_3)$ then there exists $t \in (0,1)$ such that $x_2 = tx_1 + (1-t)x_3$

Writing it as $\,x_2-x_3=t(x_1-x_3)\,$, it follows that $\,\|x_2-x_3\|=|t|\,\|x_1-x_3\|\,$. Given that $\,t\,$ is positive, this means $\,t=\dfrac{\|x_2-x_3\|}{\|x_1-x_3\|}\,$. Then $\,1-t=\dfrac{\|x_1-x_2\|}{\|x_1-x_3\|}\,$ either directly by symmetry, or using the additive property for collinear points $\,\|x_1-x_3\|=\|x_1-x_2\|+\|x_2-x_3\|\,$.

With that, the convex inequality:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
&& \color{red}{\left(t + (1-t)\right)} \cdot \color{black}{f(x_2)} &\;\le\; tf(x_1) + (1-t)f(x_3)
\\ &\iff &t\left(f(x_2)-f(x_1)\right) &\;\le\; (1-t)\left(f(x_3)-f(x_2)\right)
\\ &\iff &\frac{\|x_2-x_3\|}{\bcancel{\|x_1-x_3\|}} \left(f(x_2)-f(x_1)\right) &\;\le\; \frac{\|x_1-x_2\|}{\bcancel{\|x_1-x_3\|}} \left(f(x_3)-f(x_2)\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Your way is very interesting but it seems a little bit hard to me. I have to read to your solution to understand what you hint above.

Comment: @TungNguyen In the end there is not that much of a difference between the two, just slightly different algebraic manipulations. In the $n=1$ case, suppose $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are the three points on the graph $y=f(x)$. Your solution proves $\text{slope } X_1X_2 \le \text{slope } X_1X_3 \le \text{slope } X_2X_3$, while my answer proves $\text{slope } X_1X_2 \le \text{slope } X_2X_3$ directly.

Answer (score 3):

Since $x_2 \in (x_1,x_3)$, there exists $t \in (0,1)$ such that $x_2 = tx_1 + (1-t)x_3$. Thus we have
$$f(x_2) = f(tx_1+(1-t)x_3) \le tf(x_1) + (1-t)f(x_3).\ (1)$$
Firstly, from (1) we have
\begin{align*}
  & \dfrac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{\Vert x_2-x_1 \Vert}  \le \dfrac{(1-t)\left(f(x_3)-f(x_1)\right)}{(1-t)\Vert x_3-x_1\Vert} = \dfrac{f(x_3)-f(x_1)}{\Vert x_3 - x_1\Vert}\\ 
  \text{and }& \dfrac{f(x_3) - f(x_2)}{\Vert x_3-x_2 \Vert} \ge \dfrac{t(f(x_3)-f(x_1)}{t\Vert x_3-x_1\Vert} = \dfrac{f(x_3)-f(x_1)}{\Vert x_3-x_1\Vert}.
 \end{align*}
This yields
$$\dfrac{f(x_3) -f(x_2)}{\Vert x_3-x_2 \Vert} \ge \dfrac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{\Vert x_2-x_1\Vert}. (\text{qed}).$$

Comment: That works (+1), in fact it proves a bit more than what's strictly necessary for the proposed inequality.